# Android add more smileys in one edittext?

Tags: android

I need to add more than one smileys in a single edittext box. For add a single smiley I follow [this link](http://www.iteedu.com/handset/android/spannablediary/imagespan.php)

How to add more smileys in a single Edittext box? Thanks in advance..

Comment: where you can take the images into the edit text fields.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add as many `ImageSpan`s to a `Spannable` as you like. Just follow the concept laid out by the code you're linking. You probably want to use a `SpannableStringBuilder` too.

```
Drawable happySmiley = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy);
happySmiley .setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
Drawable sadSmiley = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sad);
sadSmiley .setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append("Some text [happy_smiley_anchor]");
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(happySmiley), builder.length()-"[happy_smiley_anchor]".length(), builder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
builder.append(". Some more text [sad_smiley_anchor]");
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(sadSmiley), builder.length()-"[sad_smiley_anchor]".length(), builder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

edittext.setText(builder);
```

Obviously you can use any anchor text/character you like - it gets replaced when the `ImageSpan` is inserted. It might even work with an empty char/string, but I didn't try that.

Comment: In this example it replaces the text from start till the end with the imagespan object...Do u have any idea how to put an imagespan just where the cursor is?

Comment: @ShailAdi: Did you try to simply set the `ImageSpan` with equal start and end (at the position of the text caret)? Alternatively, you may be need to insert a placeholder character first. And if all else fails, just start a new question here on SO. :)

Comment: @MH. yeah...I tried with the equal start and end, and it does not place the image at all... started using placeholder char for it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many `ImageSpans` to a `Spannable` as you like. Just follow the concept laid out by the code you're linking. You probably want to use a `SpannableStringBuilder` too.

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Some Text"); 
Bitmap image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage1 ); 
Bitmap image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage1 ); ssb.setSpan( new ImageSpan( image1 ), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
ssb.setSpan( new ImageSpan( image2 ), 2,3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE ); 
deleteButton.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
```

I tried above code and it works fine. I added two image span in one text view, likewise you can add as many image span to `textview`.