# What controls viber using like this EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to design a Chat Windows message.

But i cannot find the way to implement the editText control like this photo capture of Viber.

Could any one suggest me a solution. Thanks. Look at the image capture[image]

Comment: For adding an emoticon or image in EditText follow this [tutorial](http://www.iteedu.com/handset/android/spannablediary/imagespan.php). And for adding more than one Emoticon or Image in EditText, follow this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340260/android-add-more-smileys-in-one-edittext).