# How view is added in android app on button click

Tags: android

I am newbie to android development and i am learning layout and basics.I dont understand how view added at button click.Take a example of an activity which contains an text area and and edit text box with send and smiley button.So this activity layout xml file contains text area edit text and two buttons.When i press smiley smiley button a new view area is created.But that view area is not defined in xml so how is it possible?

[image]

here we have toolbar then text area and and edit text with send and smiley button theses things are defined in xml with their width and height.Now when a user press smiley button then it becomes like this.

[image]

and now a new view is created and edit box is shifted upwards.But that new view area is not defined in layout.So how we have to manage code and layout xml file to achieve this.Sorry if this question was silly.I am learning now

Comment: this link might help you:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340260/android-add-more-smileys-in-one-edittext